# I want to POST an Object in an array in JSON using RestAssured. What is the baseURI path to navigate to my Object Array

Tags: api, rest, rest-assured

This is the path where below JSON Object are available:: http://localhost:3000/FamousPersonalities

Now I want to add another Object inside the "Males" array only.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqaQD.png)

Comment: Can you please add your code as text instead of an image? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.